read_delim() in R fails to read a pipe "|" separated file vs read.table()
I´m unsuccessfuly trying to read a txt file separated with pipes "|" using readr::read_delim() function, it especificly fails reading the row number 77410 and add a missing value (NA) in a column and moves de values one column.
At lines 77408 to 77411 the original txt file contains this info:
3503|c^^ZVSS|240|2|A1|240|19.3965|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|18588.8|7|7|7|9|1|2022-12-02 09:57:02| 
3995|c^\^]SS|240|2|A1|240|19.3965|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|100300.0|6|6|6|9|1|2022-12-02 12:38:08| 
3430|_cWUTPK|240|1|A1|240|19.3965|6789.0|0.0|0.0|776.0|0.0|101.153|7|7|7|9|1|2022-12-02 14:57:01| 
3172|fa_^YWY|300|1|A1|300|19.3965|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.299|7|7|7|9|1|2022-12-02 18:01:01| 

This is the code I've used
dic_501 <- read_delim("t_501.txt",
                      delim = "|", 
                      col_names = FALSE, 
                      col_select = c(1:5, 18, 19, 20),
                      col_types = cols(X1 = col_integer(), 
                                       X2 = col_character(), 
                                       X3 = col_integer(),
                                       X4 = col_character(),
                                       X5 = col_character(),
                                       X18 = col_integer(),
                                       X19 = col_character(),
                                       X20 = col_character()
                                       ),
                      escape_backslash = FALSE, 
                      escape_double = TRUE,
                      skip_empty_rows = TRUE
                      )

This is what I get




X1
X2
X3
X4
X5
X18
X19
X20




77408
3503
c^^ZVSS
240
2
A1
1
2022-12-02 09:57:02
NA


77409
3995
c^^]SS
240
2
A1
1
2022-12-02 12:38:08
NA


77410
NA
240
1
A1
240
NA
NA
NA


77411
NA
300
1
A1
300
NA
NA
NA



This is what I expect




X1
X2
X3
X4
X5
X18
X19
X20




77408
3503
c^^ZVSS
240
2
A1
1
2022-12-02 09:57:02
NA


77409
3995
c^^]SS
240
2
A1
1
2022-12-02 12:38:08
NA


77410
3430
_cWUTPK
240
1
A1
1
2022-12-02 14:57:01
NA


77411
3172
fa_^YWY
300
1
A1
1
2022-12-02 18:01:01
NA



I use read.table() to solve this issue:
T_501 <- read.table("t_501.txt", 
                    sep = "|", 
                    header = FALSE, 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                    fill = TRUE, 
                    quote = "", 
                    skipNul = TRUE, 
                    colClasses = c("V3" = 'character', "V6" = "character"))

How can I read the file with read_delim() or any readr function?

Reading a file composed just of those 4 lines works for me with readr 2.1.5. Can you read a mini-file with just those lines? What is sessionInfo()/results of packageVersion("readr") ?

I can also read the 4 lines with readr, but with the whole file fails at line 77408, readr package is 2.1.5

read.delim assumes that you have a header line. I think you need to post the actual lines that are not getting input the way you expect.

The 4 lines alone do work. To narrow it down you can try how read_delim behaves if you read the file without the restrictions, just with read_delim("t_501.txt", delim="|", col_names=F). Also, what is utils::read.delim("t_501.txt", header=F, sep="|") doing around those failing lines?

Also  look into the source file with an editor. Maybe some weird character or a windows carriage return hiding in the txt...
